# Showing finite products exist in category of chain complexes.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am working on showing that finite products exist in the category of chain complexes over an arbitrary abelian category. I have defined the product of chain maps $A_.$, $B_.$ as the chain complex $(A_n\times B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with the differentials being the canonical maps considering the universal property of products $A_n\times B_n$ in the underlying abelian category. But I am having some trouble showing that any two consecutive differentials compose to give zero.

By universal property of product $(A_{n-1}\times B_{n-1},\pi^A_{n-1},\pi^B_{n-1})$, we have $A_{n+1}\times A_{n+1}\xrightarrow{\exists!\sigma}A_{n-1}\times A_{n-1}$, such that $\pi^A_{n-1}\sigma=0=\pi^B_{n-1}\sigma$ (because $d^A_{n-1}d^A_n=0$ and $d^B_{n-1}d^B_n=0$, where $d^A$ and $d^B$ are differentials of $A_.$, $B_.$ respectively).

I want to show $\sigma=0$, but I am not sure how I can do this legally in any abelian category (the case when the category is concrete like $R-Mod$ is straightforward). Any suggestions would be greatly helpful :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's let $d_{n-1}$ be your differential $A_n\times B_n\to A_{n-1}\times B_{n-1}$ which as you say is the map you get from the projections $A_n\times B_n\to A_n\to A_{n-1}$ and $A_n\times B_n\to B_n\to B_{n-1}$.

You just need to show $d_{n-1}d_n=0$. As you have pointed out there is a unique map $A_{n+1}\times B_{n+1}\to A_{n-1}\times B_{n-1}$ making the composition with both $\pi_{n-1}^A$ and $\pi_{n-1}^B$ zero. Check that $d_{n-1}d_n$ and $0$ both satisfy this property, and deduce $d_{n-1}d_n=0$.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that, thank you very much :))) I just need that 0 exists, but then in abelian categories between any pair of objects (unique) zero morphism exists, and its done.